# fast process to find out if files have changed in Groovy

Tags: groovy, directory

I'm writing a Groovy script that copy files from one dir to another. Currently, I'm using:

```
new AntBuilder().copy( todir:'/dest/' ) {
  fileset( dir:'src' )
```

To speed up the process, I would like the script to be smart enough to recognize files that did not change and do not copy those.

What is the most efficient way of doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to use the [`modified` ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#modified):

```
new AntBuilder().with {
  copy( todir:'/dest/' ) {
    fileset( dir:'src' ) {
      modified()
    }
  }
}
```

This works by hashing the file, and comparing it with the hash in the destination folder.

I believe though if you just do:

```
new AntBuilder().with {
  copy( todir:'/dest/', preservelastmodified:'true', overwrite:'false' ) {
    fileset( dir:'src' ) 
  }
}
```

It should only copy newer files... Adding `verbose:'true'` to the copy method should show what it is up to as well...

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone like me searching for a solution here, working with [AntBuilder sync task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sync.html) seems to be the best way:

```
new AntBuilder().sync(todir: targetDir, overwrite: true) {
    fileset(dir: sourceDir) {
    }
}
```

If you are working with jenkins pipeline, you need to annotate the method with `@NonCPS`:

```
@NonCPS
public void Synchronize() {
    new AntBuilder().sync(todir: targetDir, overwrite: true) {
        fileset(dir: sourceDir) {
        }
    }
}
```